# conditional merge with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 excel files. Lets say file A.xlsx is the main file where I work and in it I have 2 columns: Material, Location.

In file B.xlsx I have Material and Seasonality columns.

Same in fil C.xlsx, Material and Seasonality.

In the Location I have only two countries. ( France, Spain, blank values).

The file B only has the information on seasonality about France.

and file C only has the information on seasonality about Spain.

I would like to get the seasonality information from files B and C and put in a separate column (named "Seasonality) in file A corresponding to the Location value.

**df1**

```
Material    Location  
  2527       France         
  2528       Spain       
  2627       Spain      
  2628       NaN        
  2725       France
```

**df2**

**

```
Material  Seasonality
2527       Summer
2725       Autumn
```

**

**df3**

```
 Material  Seasonality
    2528       Winter
    2627       Spring
```

**desired output**

```
Material    Location         Seasonality
      2527       France      Summer
      2528       Spain       Winter
      2627       Spain       Spring
      2628       NaN         Nan
      2725       France      Autumn
```

The code I have tried is this. I know its totally wrong but I saw someone recommended to someone something like this

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_excel('A.xlsx')
df1 = pd.read_excel('B.xlsx')
df3 = pd.read_excel('C.xlsx')


df4 = pd.merge(df,df1[['Material','Seasonality']], on='Material', how='left') #merge for France
df5=pd.merge(df,df3[['Material', 'Seasonality']], on = 'Material', how='left') if df['Location']== 'Spain'

print(df5)
```

Concatonating B and C files are not possible

p.s. I dont know if it will helps or not but I already have merged the file A and B with the seasonality information on France and dataframe has now values corresponding France and NaNs (corresponding to Spain and Blank values from from Location column). Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `concat` then `groupby`

```
out = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3]).groupby('Material',as_index=False).first()
Out[90]: 
   Material Location Seasonality
0      2527   France      Summer
1      2528    Spain      Winter
2      2627    Spain      Spring
3      2628     None        None
4      2725   France      Autumn
```

Comment: I dont want to concat. If df2 and df3 only had those columns yes but. e.x df3 has 175 columns and 40k row. Is there workaround except concatenating?